# Android ViewModel to Model events

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm working on building a new Android application using Google's Architecture Components (ViewModel, LiveData) using a MVVM architecture.

I'm pretty certain I have most of the flow down already. I understand how the View uses LiveData to observe the ViewModel for changes, and how the ViewModel can similarly observe the Model (in my case, a singleton repository) for changes.

As I'm trying to keep most of my business logic in the model layer, I'd like for the View to 'report' events up to the Model layer where my business logic can decide whether/how to handle the events. Currently, my business logic can update the values in the repository which will propagate the values changes down to the View, but this is only one-directional.

How can I notify the Model of View events?

Comment: You will need to write some code to observe events coming from views (listeners), and proxy that information into your ViewModel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view can not report directly to the model. This goes against the clean architecture and the MVVM.

The ViewModel acts as the liaison between the View and the Model. The ViewModel might take input from the view and place it on the model, or it might interact with a service to retrieve the model, then translate properties and the view will be notified of the changed data through binding or observers.

If you use kotlin (and gradle 2.0 or higher) now you can [use listener bindings](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data-data-binding/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#3) for event handling and this let you execute directly methods from the ViewModel when events are triggered through lambda expressions. Its then the ViewModel who should be the one which performs the job on the model. When the model is updated the ViewModel gets notified by an observer and the View also reflects the changes with binding.

Comment: I guess I was under the belief that the ViewModel should not contain much business logic at all (As that's more of the job within the Model layer).

Comment: Exactly, you are not wrong, but its like a bridge that connects the model and the view. All the messages go in one direction and get the outputs through observers. The ViewModel should be android agnostic (only have java or kotlin code in it) and its the one in charge of getting inputs from the view and deciding what methods (or usecases in case of MVP) of the model have to be run

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now. This is a bit off topic, but I'm planning on hosting most of my business logic within a Service component (Needed as I'm using some older code as a base) - is there a way to call the Service methods from the Repository?

Comment: The repository is part of the model layer in charge of getting the data from an api. This api can be lots of different things, it's usually making api calls but it can also be reading data from files, getting data from location... So, if the service is to get the model data all looks fine to me. Most of the times when you have a repository you would also have a database to use as a cache in case the data can not be fetched at that moment

Comment: I was asking because I'm planning on using a persistent Service for my business logic (State machine, managing between different modules) because I need to use Bluetooth for all of my data. I guess I'm just trying to determine how I bridge the repository to Service communication in Java.